# What does "fatal: bad numeric config value 'ward' for 'core.safecrlf': invalid unit" mean?

Tags: git, terminal, fatal-error

When I type `git init` (or `git help tutorial`) in terminal (MacOS), I get this message:

> `fatal: bad numeric config value 'ward' for 'core.safecrlf': invalid unit`

But when I use commands like `git config --list` or `git config user.name`, it works properly.

Why do some commands work and others don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785063/1256452) has the fix you need: fix the spelling of `warn` (you have it as a typo, `ward`).  The other part of your question, though, does have an answer:

> Why do some commands work and others don't?

The *data* in a `.git/config` or `.gitconfig` or other configuration file are largely free-form, a kind of modified [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).  That is, you may create your own sections and subsections containing names and values:

```
[nadin "data"]
    why = some questions
```

which creates a new item `nadin.data.why`, whose value is `some questions`.  *Git won't care whether this setting exists, nor what this is set to* because Git has no `nadin` section, much less a `nadin.data` or `nadin.data.why` (at least not today, and probably not in the future either).

Each Git *command* can and does use whatever settings *that program* cares about.  For instance, `git commit` needs your `user.name` and `user.email` settings, so that it can write the appropriate metadata into a new commit.  The `git branch` command reads many of the `branch.*` settings, and may create some on its own for a new branch.  The `git remote` command needs to read most of the `[remote]` section (various `remote.*` items); `git push` and `git fetch` will read some subset of them.

It's only upon *reading* some value that some command that *uses* the value will notice whether the value makes any sense to that particular command.  So `git init` wants, for whatever reason, to use the `core.safecrlf` value, and reads out whatever `core.safecrlf` is set to, then demands that it be "boolean-able" (`true`, `false`, `0`, `1`, and empty all work here), or the special value `warn`.

The `git config` command is what creates, reads, and writes config files, so by design it tries not to *depend on* the configuration file: if the configuration file were required *before* the program that *writes* the configuration file can run, that would be a problem.  It's like requiring that you be a member of some club before you can join.  So `git config` *does not* depend on the `core.safecrlf` setting, and therefore cannot tell you if it's invalid.  This is a bit of a flaw in the design, but it means that you can use `git config` to *get or set* `nadin.data.why`, even though Git has never heard of such a field.

Answer (score 2):

[`core.safecrlf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresafecrlf) must be boolean (`true`, `false` or empty) or `warn`. To fix your config:

```
git config --global core.safecrlf warn
```